# Please justify the statement "Fractional lattice translation produce stacking faults"

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science

[image]

1. First, I do not understand why one complete lattice translations leads to the image as shown in the snap. In fact, there are six atom planes and if they are cut then why would one be left hanging in that fashion?
2. Where would the bottom part disappear to, and again, in contrast, how would the partial lattice translation yield a different result (stacking fault) when compared to the earlier situation?

Comment: Because that is how slip happens? The dislocation is that half-plane left hanging.

Comment: @JonCuster Correct but tell me something if the lattice distance is same as the amount of slip then how do I accommodate an extra half plane?